# Text formatting in overlay div

Tags: html, css, overlay

I'm trying to create a hover overlay on an image. I got the code from; https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_fade

I'm having an issue with the text, I am trying to put a small title and one sentence description under it. I can't seem to make it fit, as a new line pushes the above text further up, and leaving it on one paragraph tag makes it over flow.

I am using wordpress, custom-css plugin and a WYSIWYG editor.

```css
.container {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #edede7;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  white-space: pre;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="https://www.ultraframehomeimprovements.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Shakletons.png" alt="logo" width="733" height="494" />
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">
      <p><span style="font-size: small;">Inspiring products of indoor and outdoor furniture</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the text 'fit' into the hover box?

Comment: your image has a white canvas around itself... please use a perfectly cut image

Comment: Please describe more accurately what you want to achieve. As it is, I am not certain. For example, you say you want *"a small title and one sentence description under it"*, but your code only has one long sentence.

Comment: How's my answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51522610/7733026

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `<p>` and `<span>` tags and remove this line:

```
   white-space: pre;
```

and replace this:

```
   font-size: 20px;
```

with this:

```
   font-size: small;
```

That is all you need to fix it, but I have taken the liberty to simplify your code as well.

```css
.container {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #edede7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: small;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500" alt="logo"/>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">
      Inspiring products of indoor and outdoor furniture
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this:

I have removed `white-space: pre;` that was impeding the text to wrap on a new line, I also have removed the `overflow` property you put more or less everywhere, then I changed the image with one without the white canvas and changed some height and width to fit the container.

```css
.container {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
p {margin:0}
.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #edede7;
  width: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align:center;
  float: left;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt="logo" width="100%" />
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">
      <p><span style="font-size: small;">Inspiring products of indoor and outdoor furniture</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No that doesn't fix it.

Comment: Now it works. However, as I already said to MajiD, please give more description on what you changed. A block of code may help the OP, but not so much everyone else.

Comment: Also worth noting that it doesn't work so well when you resize the window.

Comment: Uhh https://s8.postimg.cc/scbevs49x/Screen_Shot_2018-07-25_at_16.50.51.png

Answer (score 0):

you mean this ?

```css
.container {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #edede7;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: small;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 0 10px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x350" alt="logo" width="733" height="494" />
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Inspiring products of indoor and outdoor furniture
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150" alt="logo" width="733" height="494" />
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Inspiring products of indoor and outdoor furniture
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x550" alt="logo" width="733" height="494" />
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Inspiring products of indoor and outdoor furniture
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good job on the code, but please give more description on what you changed. A block of code may help the OP, but not so much everyone else.